# RecyclerView onClick event is not working with SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstateadapter

Before using `FragmentStateAdapter`. I was using `FragmentPagerAdapter` then everything was fine but when I migrated from `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStateAdapter` to reduce memory usage.  The issue that I'm facing is that when `RecyclerView` is at the top position then clicking on any item in the list is not working. If I scroll the `RecyclerView` a bit down then onClick works fine. This problem was not happening with `SwipeRefreshLayout`. When I remove `SwipeRefreshLayout` from parent of `RecyclerView`. It working fine. How can I use it with `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

I'm using children Fragments inside a parent Fragment like this
[image]

This is the code of Parent Fragment.

```
public class DailyFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentDailyBinding binding;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentDailyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        MyChildFragmentAdapter childFragmentAdapter = new MyChildFragmentAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager(), this.getLifecycle()); // I'm showing these fragment in Parent fragment. So that I'm using getChildFragmentManager() 
        childFragmentAdapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment(),"first");
        childFragmentAdapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment(),"second");
        childFragmentAdapter.addFragment(new ThirdFragment(),"third");
        childFragmentAdapter.addFragment(new FourthFragment(),"fourth");
        childFragmentAdapter.addFragment(new FifthFragment(),"fifth");
        binding.dailyViewPager.setAdapter(childFragmentAdapter);
        new TabLayoutMediator(binding.dailyTabLayout, binding.dailyViewPager, (tab, position) -> tab.setText(childFragmentAdapter.fragmentsArrayListTitle.get(position))).attach();
        binding.dailyViewPager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    // FragmentStateAdapter
    public static class MyChildFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
        private final ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final ArrayList<String> fragmentsArrayListTitle = new ArrayList<>();

        public MyChildFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
            super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        }



        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragmentsArrayList.add(fragment);
            fragmentsArrayListTitle.add(title);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            return fragmentsArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return fragmentsArrayList.size();
        }

    }
}
```

and This this XML of `FirstFragment()`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChieldFragment.dailyChield.MahadevFragment">
    
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/mahadevSwipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mahadevRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is similar to this question

[ViewPager2 conflicting with SwipeRefreshLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61115361/16765223)

I checked these answers but not solved my problem.

Comment: Not sure, but Can you disable the nested scrolling of the ViewPager2 RecyclerView (if you are using VP2); [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749500/how-to-enable-dragging-on-viewpager2-inside-bottomsheetdialogfragment/67865776#67865776)

Comment: @Zain Yes, I'm using ViewPager2. I think this problem occurred with Nested Scrolling of ViewPager2. Because when my images are getting loaded then my device is also hanging.

Comment: Great.. Have you tried disabling it?

Comment: @Zain Sorry, But the problem is not solved yet. My ViewPager2 is Showing correctly but unable to click on the top position of Images. When I scroll the `RecyclerView` a bit down then onClick works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem not so long ago. I fixed mine by adding NestedScrollView as SwipeRefreshLayout child, and then simply put your recycler layout as NestedScrollView's child. See example below :

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/mahadevSwipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        // I didn't put mandatory constraints, but you'll have to
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/mahadevRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Alternatively, you could also keep your code like it is, and add custom scrolling behavior with scroll listener.
Tell me if my first guess don't work, i'll give you example of custom scroll handling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked `NestedScrollView` but it consumes `3X memory` and also hangs the device. I think this is not a suitable method to solve this problem.

Comment: In certain conditions. Your NestedScrollView helped to solve this. This is good if you add your second method to your question. If some developers have another issue. Then they can try your second method if this one is not works.

Comment: @MDev I was aiming at giving solution with minimum changes involved. IMHO, best solution would be getting rid of swipe to refresh layout and implement a custom behavior to recylcerView, and thus making it custom swipeToRefresh without hassle of nesting behavior-conflicting-layouts.

Comment: yeah, it is also good if I use `ProgressBar` to refresh my layout. Anyway `NestedScrollView` solved my problem with certain conditions. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: oh didn't think of that, clever workaround ! No problem, thanks for the bounty ;)

Comment: This error was also asked in Android issue Tracker. And solved by changing its parent layout. If anyone Facing this type of error try to change the Parent Layout of `SwipeRefreshLayout` like `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout`. or try this answer or try this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/61115487/16765223

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to all views under coordinator layout.

Comment: @jaunje Thank you for your answer. but this also not solved my answer. `NestedScrollView` work. But it is good if you have any other answer to solve this without `NestedScrollView`. Otherwise, it works with `NestedScrollView`(but something also problem with nested)